# Trouble installing AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line tool packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble installing AWS Elastic Beanstalk command line tool and I don't understand why. I've downloaded the package from AWS and followed the instruction carefully. Following is the installation instruction:

> ```
> == Installation
>
> Once you have downloaded the CLI package:
>
> 1) Unzip this archive to a location of your choosing.
>
> Eb is located in the "eb" directory. The complete CLI reference 
> for more advanced scenarios can be found in the "api" directory.
>
> To add eb files to your path:
>
> Linux/Mac OS X (Bash shell):
>
> export PATH=$PATH:<path to eb>
>
> Windows:
>
> set PATH=<path to eb>;%PATH%
> ```

I'm using Mac OS X so I've used export PATH=$PATH:. For the path to eb, I've just copied the file into the terminal, which resulted `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/lydia/Downloads/ElasticBeanstalk/eb/macosx/python2.7/eb`. I'm not sure what I'm missing and I can't deploy without downloading eb command line first.

Comment: You haven't actually said what the problem you're having is.  Afaik, installing beanstalk on Mac is simply a case of unzipping the download somewhere sensible (under downloads is probably not a good idea), and then adding the eb folder to your path.  That's it.  Now you can run programs in the eb folder.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the eb at the end so it's just

> /Users/lydia/Downloads/ElasticBeanstalk/eb/macosx/python2.7/

this worked for me although i can only get it to work if i export the CLI into the specific website folder i am working on see my question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/428417/aws-elastic-beanstalk-command-line-tool-setup

Answer (score 1):

Fix that worked for me (if you installed python using brew) is remove python via

```
brew uninstall --force python
```

and then install it again from https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Then just follow the instructions from AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You only add directories to your `$PATH`. Is `~/Downloads/ElasticBeanstalk/eb/macosx/python2.7/eb` a directory? Or is it the actual command?